# Graphic not displaying as a figure

Tags: graphics, floats

EDIT: I found the solution for the problem. The `float` package is necessary to use figures in a `multicol` environment.

When trying to insert an image into a document, I am unable to use a figure. This following code describes what I am trying to do, but it is not functional.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics{image}
\end{figure}
```

On the other hand, not declaring the image as a figure works. The following code is functional, but since the image is not a figure, I cannot properly caption and whatnot:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\includegraphics{image}
```

How do I properly insert the image as a graphic, so that I can work with it more?

Comment: `multicol` is bad in handling floats. Don't use figure but only `\includegraphics` and for caption, use `\captionof` from `caption` package.

Comment: Using a figure has worked in the past though, with multicol.